# Minimum values between multiple columns ignoring zero and null value columns

Tags: sql, minimum

I want to create a new variable called `Market_Min` from the following 5 columns where:

```
Col 1 is 0
Col 2 is 100
Col 3 is 200
Col 4 is 150
Col 5 is NULL
```

The answer should be 100 in this case.

Comment: Do you care which language is used? Could you use some spreadsheet software like Excel or LibreOffice?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention... Its in SQL

Comment: Why is `100` the correct answer?  Are you looking for the minimum positive non-null number?

Comment: Currently im using the following code: CASE WHEN Col1 > 0 then (CASE WHEN isnull(Col1,999999) <= isnull(Col2,999999) AND isnull(Col1,999999) <= isnull(Col3,999999) AND isnull(Col1,999999) <= isnull(Col4,999999) AND isnull(Col1,999999) <= isnull(Col5,999999) THEN Col1 END) when Col2 > 0 then (CASE WHEN isnull(Col2,999999) <= isnull(Col1,999999) AND isnull(Col2,999999) <= isnull(Col3,999999) AND isnull(Col2,999999) <= isnull(Col4,999999) AND isnull(Col2,999999) <= isnull(Col5,999999) THEN Col2 END) and so on until col5.. but this is giving me all Market_Min values as NULL :(

Comment: yes.. im looking for non null and non zero minimum number as the answer..

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Im working on SQL Server Management Studio.. im very new to using these softwares..

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `union all` to get the minimum value across the entire table:

```
select min(combinedcol)
from (
    select col1 combinedcol from yourtable union all
    select col2 from yourtable union all
    select col3 from yourtable union all
    select col4 from yourtable union all
    select col5 from yourtable
) t
where coalesce(combinedcol,0) > 0
```

---

**Edit base on comments**

If you need a minimum value per row, you can introduce a `row_number` in your subquery and `group by` it:

```
select rn, min(combinedcol)
from (
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn, col1 combinedcol from yourtable union all
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn, col2 from yourtable union all
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn, col3 from yourtable union all
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn, col4 from yourtable union all
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn, col5 from yourtable
) t
where coalesce(combinedcol,0) > 0
group by rn
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbdb4/4)

Comment: Ahh! It worked.. but it gives me a single minimum value.. I actually have 1000 rows and 5 columns and I want to get a minimum value for each row.. Apologies for the confusion..Please help

Comment: I basically want to add a new column to the data showing minimum of each row across the 5 columns

Comment: @user3637879 -- you need a row_number to group on.  If you have an id, that would be best.  If not, you can create one like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbdb4/4

Comment: For example, Row 1: Col 1 is 0
Col 2 is 100
Col 3 is 200
Col 4 is 150
Col 5 is NULL, Row 2: Col 1 is 400
Col 2 is 120
Col 3 is 200
Col 4 is 150
Col 5 is NULL.. I want to add Col 6 as Market_Min with Row 1 value as 100 and Row 2 as 120

Comment: Great answer sgeddes.  You can get the min val per row using the above if you have a row identifier to group by.  I.e  RecordId, MIN(ComineCol) .... stuff ... GROUP BY RecordId

Answer (score 0):

To use a different approach using fn_Split

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE (col1 int, col2 int,  col3 int, col4 int , col5 int)

INSERT INTO @Temp
    (col1 , col2 ,  col3 , col4 , col5 )
VALUES
    ( 0, 200, 100, 150,NULL)
SELECT
    *
    ,
    (
    SELECT 
        MIN(Value) 
    FROM 
        dbo.fn_Split
        (
          CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(col1,0),99999) AS VARCHAR(10)) +','
        + CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(col2,0),99999) AS VARCHAR(10)) +','
        + CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(col3,0),99999) AS VARCHAR(10)) +','
        + CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(col4,0),99999) AS VARCHAR(10)) +','
        + CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(col5,0),99999) AS VARCHAR(10))
        ,','
        )
    ) AS MinNonZeroNonNullValue
FROM
    @Temp
```

You will need to add the fn_Split function to the server. Which you can download [Here](http://blogs.interfacett.com/fn_split-table-valued-function-by-sql-instructor-jeff-jones)